# vue-select, buefy CSS not working on production | NUXT.JS

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, buefy, vue-select

I am using buefy autocomplete component with nuxt.js. I have imported the CSS file. and the CSS working properly on the localhost but on the live server is not working. I thought the problem may be with buefy but the same problem I am facing with vue-select autocomplete.

Everything is perfect on the local server but when I move my files to live server and do `num run build` noting works from buefy and vue-select.

Note: the rest of all CSS working just fine

**Localhost**

[image]

**Production**

[image]

And it's not only autocomplete component, none of the buefy components are working, Radio Buttons, Calender etc.

A little guidance will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me. How did you setup buefy? Did you have an existing nuxt project when you were adding it ?

Comment: Can you please check this -> https://codeshare.io/2KMrN8  This is how i setup the buefy

Comment: Try setting up buefy as I mentioned in the answer, see if it works and let me know if you are still having problems also with vue-select.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Buefy has an official support for Nuxt. Instead of importing buefy's css inside `nuxt.config.js` and creating a new plugin, you can use a [nuxt module](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/modules/).

If you create a new Nuxt project using [`create-nuxt-app`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation#using-code-create-nuxt-app-code-), you can choose to add Buefy as your UI framework.

If you have an existing nuxt project, you can simply install the [`nuxt-buefy`](https://github.com/buefy/nuxt-buefy) module manually:

```sh
npm i nuxt-buefy
```

*nuxt.config.js*

```js
...,
modules: [
  'nuxt-buefy',
],
...
```

Comment: Hey, @htmn thanks for the answer but still the same. I did exactly but the CSS is not working

Comment: Did you also try running the preconfigured server `npm run build` and then `npm run start` ?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually I have managed it with vue-select CDN css for now. but I know its not a solution.

Comment: That is strange, what version of nuxt are you using ? I can see that inside your `nuxt.config.js` you are still using `ssr: false`, which is [deprecated](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#client-side-only) and it is now adapted to `mode: 'client'` option. I'm just shooting into dark here, is it a private project, do you have a repo available to share ? Also if it's not a large project I would consider starting fresh and just use `npx create-nuxt-app`, because buefy is working fine for me after I selected it as my UI framework and ran `npm run start`.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue @htmn, did you find a solution at the end ?